# woocommerce address_2 dropdown placeholder not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, drop-down-menu

I have created address_2 as a dropdown but the placeholder is not showing.

```
/* address_2 dropdown */


add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'address2_dropdown' );

function address2_dropdown( $address_fields ) {

    // address_2
    $address_fields['address_2']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Adresse';
    $address_fields['address_2']['options'] = array(
        '' => '',
        'villa' => 'Villa',
        'apartment'    => 'Apartment',
        'other'  => 'Other',        
    );
    
    // Sort
    ksort($address_fields['address_2']['options']);

    return $address_fields;
}
```

I used the code above to make the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In select box placeholder is first blank option.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'address2_dropdown' );

function address2_dropdown( $address_fields ) {

    // address_2
    $address_fields['address_2']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['address_2']['options'] = array(
        '' => 'Address',
        'villa' => 'Villa',
        'apartment'    => 'Apartment',
        'other'  => 'Other',        
    );

    // Sort
    ksort($address_fields['address_2']['options']);

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015385/12536243

here is the code if someone wants to use for address_2

```
// Change "address"  to a dropdown
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'override_address_2_dropdown' );
function override_address_2_dropdown( $address_fields ) {

    // Define here in the array your desired name 
    $option_unit_type = array(
         '' => __( 'Select unit type' ),
        'villa' => 'Villa',
        'apartment' => 'Apartment',
        'other' => 'Other',
    );

    $address_fields['address_2']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['address_2']['options'] = $option_unit_type;


    return $address_fields;
}
```